# Is there a defined TimeSpan value for "Indefinite"?

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, task

In .NET many methods that accept a TimeSpan treat `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)` as an indefinite-wait. This is relatively easy to type and can be defined as such:

```
static class CaroselsAndSuch {
   static readonly TimeSpan IndefiniteWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);
   // etc etc blah bling golden rings
```

However, this feels like a relatively common situation- Is there a similar 'constant' definition lurking around the core .NET / Task libraries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan Field**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinitetimespan(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
TimeSpan infiniteTimeSpan = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
```

> A constant used to specify an infinite waiting period, for methods
>   that accept a TimeSpan parameter.

Comment: Odd that this constant is defined on `System.Threading.Timeout` rather than `System.TimeSpan`.

Comment: @ToddMenier: Well, `System.TimeSpan` doesn't have "infinity" semantics for this value. For instance, `TimeSpan.FromHours(50) < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)` is false.

Comment: Ah, good point. It gets special treatment within the `System.Threading` world. That makes sense.